# Is it possible to write a single BQ Query that reads from external table and writes to multiple tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need your expert advice on the below query, your help is greatly appreciated.

**Query:**
I have an External Table (in GCS), I have a requirement to read this table every 5 mins(300GB) and run multiple filters/transformations/aggregations on that data and insert the results into 8 different tables.

**Example:**

> INSERT INTO ds.Native_Cube1 (col1,col2, sumagg) SELECT
> col1,col2,sum(col25) as sumagg FROM ds.External_Table Where
> CAST(SUBSTR(_FILE_NAME,43,12) AS INT64) > 123456 GROUP BY sumagg
>
> INSERT INTO ds.Native_Cube2 (col1,col2, col3, meancol5) SELECT
> col1,col2,col3,mean(col5) as meancol5 FROM ds.External_Table Where
> CAST(SUBSTR(_FILE_NAME,43,12) AS INT64) > 123456 AND col3=http GROUP
> BY meancol5

...8 such queries.

With this approach I end up reading the input data multiple times and pay for it. I want to read the input data only once and populate these native_cubeN tables appropriately.

**So the question is, Is it possible to avoid these extra reads and cost? If Yes, please suggest how can achieve.**

Thank you for listening to me.

Answer (score 0):

A query can only update one table, so maybe you can try to reduce the read cost for each query instead. It seems all your queries have a filter on `CAST(SUBSTR(_FILE_NAME,43,12) AS INT64)`. A possible way to reduce cost is to import the external table into a native table, partitioned on a column with value `CAST(SUBSTR(_FILE_NAME,43,12) AS INT64)`. Then queries would read from this native table, with filters on the partitioning column. The queries would only read the matching partitions, instead of the whole table.